# C# visual control for editing statements / equations / conditions?

Tags: c#, user-interface, properties, controls

Basically what i need is an editor for a logical statement or equation or condition. 
 I am looking to do something like what is shown in http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xFUWtztPibs  at 1min 20sec and on, and i thought maybe I'll be re-inventing the wheel and its already there as a control you can just use.

Example: there is a class that has the following properties:

- variable_name (string)
- comparator (enum)
- value (object)

This class represents a condition of a kind:

```
If <variable_name> <comparator> <value>
```

which can hold conditions like:

```
If x != 0
If temp <= 100
If currentChapter > 3
```

etc.

It can be more complex - like, `If 3dpoint(x,y,z) is outside a sphere(x,y,z,r)` or even something like `if (a>b) and ((3d point is inside a rectangle) or (not(b<c)))` etc.

User should be able to edit theese conditions (specifically, the class's properties) in a manner that shown in the video - the condition is displayed in a form of simple text (like Label control), with changeable "parts" highlited and clickable (Label that is a hyperlink), clicking them shows a modal window that allows you to change them.

Like, when you select a new condition from my example, it shows:

```
If <variable_name> <comparator> <value>
```

If you click the `<comparator>`, you are allowed to chose from `=, !=, >, <`etc and if you click the `<variable_name>`, you are allowed to chose from list of already used variables or type a new one. After you specify it, labels change to:

```
If variable_1 != <value>
```

Of course i can make this kind of interface myself by dynamically adding and removing labels inside some TabLayout control, hooking OnClick events to those of the labels that represent changeable parts, but maybe, just maybe, something like that is already done and available?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The place that you are most likely to find this sort of thing is on [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/), so i recommend searching there.

Comment: I tried looking there but just searching returns no results and the amount of articles is huge, after ~1 hour of looking i didnt find anything... maybe you could suggest what search terms should i use? I just... dont know how to call that which i want to find...

Comment: What about [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27654/General-Expression-Parser-and-Evaluator) or [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7335/An-extensible-math-expression-parser-with-plug-ins) or theres half a dozen more to choose from. Happy hunting

Comment: i googled "codeproject expression parser"

Comment: Thanks alot. You see i'm russian and i cant always find good search terms for stuff in english, like in russian graph always means the graph from theory of graphs, but in english you'll find more function visualisations and plots/etc for this search term, even though the word "graph" does mean the theory of graphs's graph too.

Comment: Erm, this isnt what i need at all. This "expression parser" takes a string and converts it to mathematical expressions, but i need a GUI editor for the expression/statement i already know (like, i know this is an "if A (comparator) B" statement, i need a gui to edit the value of A, comparator, and B.

Comment: i think that what you are after is very specific, and if you have aleready implemented the logic then just go ahead and create your own UI. Win Forms will make it quick and easy for you.

Comment: Well, i just have gone through implementing a GUI and when i found about propertyGrid and felt like a fool, so i thought, maybe this is also already implemented and i'll invent the wheel again...

Comment: then maybe go through [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ettb6e2a.aspx)